# How do I inverse cv2.warpPerspective in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

I am testing an algorithm to align images with the ultimate goal of aligning two images taken from different perspectives. I would like to be able to transform, then un-transform an image using transformation matrices.

I am able to generate the 3*3 transformation matrix H, and I have the original image img:

```
warped_image = cv2.warpPerspective(img, H, (320,240))
```

Now I want to transform warped_image back. i.e.

```
restored_image = cv2.warpPerspective(warped_image, H_inv, (320, 240))
```

How do I calculate the inverse transformation matrix `H_inv`?

Comment: Can you provide more context?  What is the overall goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I am testing an algorithm that could align images. So the ultimate goal would be aligning two images taken from different perspectives. I kind of have the way to generate transformation matrices now, but I am still learning how to use the transformation matrix.

Comment: So the overall goal would be using warped_image and H to restore the orignial image, which is img.

Comment: just invert the transformation matrix H (matrix inverse)